# c++ value at address is different than expected after function call

Tags: c++, pointers, arduino

lately, I was trying to solve one problem, that bugged me for a while.

The problem was, that when I called a method and passed a struct, which had an array pointer as a member, the first two bytes were nulled after the method returned. Even though they were initialized as (in this case) 0xFF. They weren't nulled always. Sometimes happened, that they actually carried some value, but I couldn't find out any pattern.

I recently solved it. I had to pass a pointer for the Bitmap struct. But I don't see why, when I only needed to change the value of the array and as you can see below, i was writing to the same address, but when it returned from the method, 2 first bytes were zero;

Can somebody, please, explain what I am missing? Thanks.

I had this code:

```
void Printer::offsetBitmapVertically(Bitmap bitmap, uint8_t offset)
{
    byte length = bitmap.arrayLength();

    byte previousValue = 0;

    for (byte i = 0; i < bitmap.width; i++)
    {
        byte previousValue = 0;
        for (byte j = 0; j <= bitmap.height / 8; j++)
        {
            byte index = i + bitmap.width * j;

            byte tmp = bitmap.value[index] >> 8 - offset;
            bitmap.value[index] = (bitmap.value[index] << offset) | previousValue;
            Serial.print("address: "); Serial.println((uint16_t)&bitmap.value[index]);
            Serial.print("value: "); Serial.println(bitmap.value[index], HEX);
            previousValue = tmp;
        }
    }

    Serial.println("");
    Serial.println("");
    Serial.println("");
}

void TextPrinter::print(const char *str, Point p, Font* p_font)
{
    while (*str)
    {
        Bitmap bitmap = p_font->getBitmapFromCharacter(*str);
        offsetBitmapVertically(bitmap, 0);
        for (int i = 0; i < bitmap.arrayLength(); i++)
        {
            Serial.print("address: "); Serial.println((uint16_t)&bitmap.value[i]);
            Serial.print("value: "); Serial.println(bitmap.value[i], HEX);
        }

        p_lcd->writeBitmap(bitmap.value, p.x, p.y, bitmap.width, bitmap.height);
        p.x += bitmap.width + 2;

        str++;
    }  
}

/*
address: 1240
value: FF
...
address: 1241
value: FF
...



address: 1240
value: 0
address: 1241
value: 0
...
*/
```

Bitmap struct was defined like this

```
struct Bitmap
{
    public:
        Bitmap(const byte* bitmapArray);
        ~Bitmap() { delete [] value; }

        uint8_t arrayLength() { return arrayLength(width, height); } 
        static uint8_t arrayLength(uint8_t width, uint8_t height) { return width * ((height / 8) + 1); } // TODO potencional bug when height % 8 == 0

        byte* value;
        uint8_t width;
        uint8_t height;
};

Bitmap::Bitmap(const byte* bitmapArray)
{
    width = pgm_read_word(bitmapArray);
    height = pgm_read_word(bitmapArray + 1);

    byte length = arrayLength(width, height);
    value = new byte[length];
    for (byte i = 0; i < length; i++)
        value[i] = pgm_read_word(bitmapArray + i + 2); // first two bytes were width and height
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You pass the `bitmap` variable *by value*. That means the `offsetBitmapVertically` function receives a *copy* of the variable from the `print` function.

Changing the copy will of course not change the original.

You should probably pass the argument *by reference*:

```
void Printer::offsetBitmapVertically(Bitmap& bitmap, uint8_t offset) { ... }
//                                         ^
//                       Note ampersand here
```

---

Also note that your code leads to *undefined behavior* unless you change to pass by reference. That is because the default copy-constructor (which will be used to create the copy) just copy the pointer, leading to two different object having the same pointer to the same memory. Once the `bitmap` variable inside the `offsetBitmapVertically` function goes out of scope and is destructed it will `delete[]` that memory, meaning that the original pointer no longer points to allocated memory.

Read about [the rules of three, five and zero](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/rule_of_three) to learn how to fix this.

Comment: Yes, thank you, but that actually doesn't answer my question. 
I was writing to the right address (1240, 1241, ..), but after the method return only two first bytes were null. Every other had expected value.

Comment: @redsnake So the question isn't why the modification you made to the variable `bitmap` in the `offsetBitmapVertically` function persist to the `print` function?

Comment: @redsnake Also, are you *sure* that the addresses are only 16 bits? They're not 32 bits?

Comment: @redsnake You're harboring a [Rule of Three/Five/Zero](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/rule_of_three) violation with your bitmap class. The default copy-ctor member-copies everything in your bitmap (meaning, pointers, sizes, etc), upon function exit, `Bitmap::~Bitmap` is fired, which destroys that array, leaving you a dangling pointer in the original object (the source of the copy). Passing by reference as shown by this answer avoids that. Since that class is not RO3-safe, putting `Bitmap(const Bitmap&) = delete;` in your class decl should flag all the places you're victim of this.

Comment: @redsnake `bitmap.value[index] = ...` definitely looks like a modification to me. However, as I have updated my answer and as noted by WhozCraig the problem is probably something else. The (temporary) solution is the same though.

Comment: thank you both for your help. I finally understood why :-)

PS: addresses are 16bit because it is for Arduino.